# How to freeze an Adobe Muse composition widget when scrolling the page

Tags: web-development

I am using Adobe Muse to build a website for learning purposes.

For the menu bar, I try to create my own custom menu using composition widget. And then, I tried to freeze that composition widget so that whenever the browser being scroll down, it will freeze as it should be. The user will not have to scroll all the way back to the top.

However, the scrolling effect that I tried to create was unsuccessful. I've tried to use rectangle box and put the trigger for the widget onto it but still no luck.